# Is there a way to disable multi login for only some users in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is there a way to disable multi login for only some users in liferay?

We can always disable multiple login for all the users by using the below mentioned parameters in the portal-ext.properties file :

```
auth.simultaneous.logins=false
live.users.enabled=true
```

But how can we allow multiple access for some of the users while disabling multiple access for others?

I am using liferay-6.2-ga-ce for the development.

Comment: There's no configuration for such an option, but you can implement a custom LoginAction, to be triggered on every login. There you can implement the condition (e.g. list of names) that you'd like to cover. And then you can decide if you terminate the current (newest) session or the older session. Or signal alarm.

Comment: what will be the configuration for this case and also can I please get a sample if possible?

Comment: Sorry, implementation service is off-topic on stackoverflow. Plus, your version is 2-3 years, or 3 versions, out of date: I don't even have that development environment around any more.